# Error "No Overload for method 'Fill' takes 2 arguments" with 2 tables here which is joined

Tags: c#, winforms

i always got an error "No Overload for method 'Fill' takes 2 arguments" in this code. i use 2tables here which is joined. please help me

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter apter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter();
        DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable table = new DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable();

        apter.Fill(table,textBox1.Text);

        ReportDataSource NewDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", (DataTable)table);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(NewDataSource);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Remove `textBox1.Text`, just use `apter.Fill(table);`

Comment: If you're learning C#/.NET, then a hint: skip datatables and look at Entity Framework.

Comment: @HenkHolterman +1, however learning ADO.NET is not a waste of time, a newbie can learn it in 5 to 10 days and that's not very useless.

Comment: @keyboardP how can i add a constructor in DataTable1TableAdapter?

Comment: @KingKing - agreed, but the ADO.NET foundation is Commands, Parameters and DataReaders. Not DataSet/DataTable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `DataSet` and `DataTable` are disconnected classes (a half part of Ado.net) while `Command`, `DataAdapter`, `DataReader`, ... are connected classes (the other half of Ado.NET), of course the connected classes are more fundamental things, but personally I see the both are equally important.

Answer (score 2):

There's a error in

```
  apter.Fill(table,textBox1.Text); // <- No such method, consult MSDN
```

See, *the answer is in the exception message*: "No Overload for method 'Fill' takes 2 arguments". Put

```
  apter.Fill(table);
```

Comment: do you know how to add a constructor in my DataTable1TableAdapter?

Comment: @user2650781 - what do you need a constructor for?

Comment: in my form, i actually want to make a search in my reportviewer so i make that code and i put the textBox1.Text in the method so that whatever i type on  the txtbox the reportviewer can search it

Comment: You can use the Adapter design tools to create a FillBySomething method.

Comment: No, too long ago. Look on MSDN etc for articles from 2001 - 2005.

Answer (score -3):

Change your fields datatype to Text and try again...

After getter success then again change that field to whatever datatype...